# AmpersandJS: How to transform model data before displaying in a view

Tags: view, ampersand.js

In an AmpersandJS view, is there a convention for transforming data from a model? For example, I'd like to be able to format a `user.joined` date within the view before it's displayed.  I'd rather not have to do this in the model.

Maybe something like:

```
var View = require('ampersand-view');
var formatDate = require('../helpers/format-date');

module.exports = View.extend({
  bindings: {
    'model.joined': {
      hook: 'joined',
      transform: function(date) { return formatDate(date) }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not limited to `model` when using bindings. You can also bind to properties on the view and since `AmpersandView` extends `AmpersandState` these properties may also be derived, like:

```js
var View = require('ampersand-view');
var formatDate = require('../helpers/format-date');

module.exports = View.extend({
  derived: {
    formattedJoinedDate: {
      deps: ['model.joined'],
      fn: function() { return formatDate(this.model.joined) }
    }
  }
  bindings: {
    'this.formattedJoinedDate': {
      hook: 'joined'
    }
  }
});
```

[Docs that cover bindings to local properties](http://ampersandjs.com/docs#ampersand-dom-bindings-other-benefits)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `View` extends `State`, so you can setup properties in your view definition to bind to.  Inside your `View.extend`, you can instantiate things in the `props` hash, just like you would with `ampersand-model` or `ampersand-state`, and then setup bindings on them!

```
var View = require('ampersand-view');
var formatDate = require('../helpers/format-date');

module.exports = View.extend({
  props: { someDate: 'date' },
  bindings: {
    someDate: {
      hook: 'joined',
      transform: function(date) { return formatDate(date) }
    }
  },
  initialize: function() { this.someDate = new Date(); }
});
```